# Snapping an NSWindows in place while the user is moving it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

What would be the best way to snap an `NSWindow` to some location while the user is moving it?

I have tried using `windowDidMove`, for mouse down events, but this function is called for every single movement. I haven't been able to find anything equivalent to the old `kEventWindowBoundsChanging` with `kWindowBoundsChangeUserDrag`, which was exactly what was needed to do this. It needs to be available in `10.7` on up.

Any leads?

Comment: Have you tried `window`**Will**`Move:`?

Comment: Well, it gets called as often as windowDidMove. Plus, it is just a notification.

Comment: "Just a notification" meaning you're not supposed to change the origin from that method?

Comment: See if this helps: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MagneticWindows

Answer (score 0):

Generally the easiest way to do this is subclass NSWindow and implement `-setFrame:`, where you modify the `NSRect` argument and then pass it to `super`.